# Is there a length limit to String in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, logcat

I managed to read a web page into a string, but when I print it to LogCat, using Log.d(), It always displays less than what's really on that page.

Which leads me to suspect that one (or more) of the following are possible explanations:

1. In Android, a String can grow
   dynamically, but it is eventually
   bound by some hard coded MAX_LENGTH.
2. Log.d() is the one truncating a
   String output.

Is there a length limit to a String in Android?

If not, what could possible explain truncating my string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its the logcat that is not able to display whole text , print the output of the logcat to a file , I think you should be able to see the whole String.

Comment: You are right. I just tried logging, via Log.d(), only the last 10th of the string, and it definitely prints </body>. :)

Answer (score 0):

True, Log.d() truncates the tail end above some MAX_LENGTH, but

```
System.out.println (string);
```

outputs the whole string.